# QT - QGridLayout Different Spacing of Header Row needed

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have a QGridLayout and i need the spacing in all rows but not in the first one. How can i achieve this? In the image below you see the space between the cells. I can set the spacing with:

```
self.grid.setSpacing(0)
```

but this will affect the entire Grid.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details. Your question is unclear.

Comment: I made some edits. is it more clear?

Comment: You want no spacing between cells in the first row, but spacing between cells in the subsequent rows? Are you talking about horizontal or vertical spacing (or both?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done quite easily by removing the horizontal spacing and using *columnSpan* on the header labels.

Here's a simple demo script:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setHorizontalSpacing(0)
        self.setStyleSheet('background: black; color: white')
        headers = 'Name: Item: Color: Status:'.split()
        for column, header in enumerate(headers):
            label = QtGui.QLabel(header)
            label.setStyleSheet('background: silver; padding: 5px')
            if column < len(headers) - 1:
                layout.addWidget(label, 0, 2 * column, 1, 2)
                layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(2 * column + 1, 10)
            else:
                layout.addWidget(label, 0, 2 * column)
            widget = QtGui.QWidget()
            widget.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid white')
            layout.addWidget(widget, 1, 2 * column)
        layout.setRowStretch(1, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 450, 90)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thats the answer i was waiting for!

Comment: If you increase the height of the window, the header also gets stretched, I think this should not happen.

Comment: This might look like header but does not behave like that.

Comment: @qurban. I made a small adjustment to fix the header height. But my demo script was only intended to answer the OPs specific question about horizontal spacing (which I think it does). There are probably other adjustments that *could* be made, but that would seem to go beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: Of course your solution is a smart way to solve the OP's problem. But I just wanted to establish the point that the header should be of **fixed height**

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic in Qt to achieve that. You will need to create your own header separately, you can do this by creating a horizontal layout inside a QWidget. In the `resizeEvent` of widget in which the gridlayout lives, you will need to explicitly change the width of the widgets inside the header layout, according to the width of widgets in each column of the gridlayout.

If you don't want to do this, consider using a `QTableWidget`, it contains a built-in header

Comment: what is the big difference between QTableWidget and QGridLayout?

Comment: As it's name says, QTableWidget is a widget, that means it will offfer more control to handle the size, events, etc. Moreover you can efficiently work with the items inside QTableWidget, because they are `QTableWidgetItem`. These items will also offer some handy methods. Your situation suits more to use QTableWidget

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to have no spacing (using `setSpacing(0)`) between items in your `QGridLayout`. This achieves the goal of no spacing between the headers.

To achieve the spacing between items in the subsequent rows you could introduce another layout around each item, with spacers or empty widgets on either side.

---

Alternatively, you could insert columns in the grid layout between your current items (while still having `setSpacing(0)` set). Items in the header row of these columns could be styled to appear as if they were part of the header items you currently have.